# why wifstream.read function is not reading data to variable?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream

I have a structure which is:

```
struct purchase_order_details{
    wstring number;
    wstring date;
    wstring vender_code;
    void Write(wofstream&);
    void Read(wifstream&);
    size_t totalSizeInFile;
};
```

the functions above are implemented as below:

```
void purchase_order_details::Write(wofstream& wofs)
{
    size_t totalSize = 0;

    size_t s1 = this->date.size(); totalSize += s1;
    wofs.write((wchar_t*)&s1, sizeof(s1));
    wofs.write(  this->date.c_str() , s1 );

    s1 = this->number.size(); totalSize += s1;
    wofs.write((wchar_t*)&s1, sizeof(s1));
    wofs.write(  this->number.c_str() , s1 );

    s1 = this->vender_code.size(); totalSize += s1;
    wofs.write((wchar_t*)&s1, sizeof(s1));
    wofs.write(  this->vender_code.c_str() , s1 );

    totalSizeInFile = totalSize;
}

void purchase_order_details::Read(wifstream& wifs)
{
size_t sz=0;

wifs.read((wchar_t*)&sz, sizeof(sz));
wchar_t * date = new wchar_t[sz];
wifs.read(date, sz);
this->date = date;

wifs.read((wchar_t*)&sz, sizeof(sz));
wchar_t * number = new wchar_t[sz];
wifs.read(number, sz);
this->number = number;

wifs.read((wchar_t*)&sz, sizeof(sz));
wchar_t * vcode = new wchar_t[sz];
wifs.read(vcode, sz);
this->vender_code = vcode;

delete []date;
delete []number;
delete []vcode;
}
```

because my structure contains a `wstring` therefore i have to implement a different method of reading and writing the data from the file.

the problem is that in `Read` function `wifs.read((wchar_t*)&sz, sizeof(sz));` and the other one too, are not reading the value from the file to the variable.

The file passed to both function is binary.

Why it is not reading the value to the variable? what is the solution?

thanks in advance and for any advice.

Comment: Doing IO and no error checking is disaster(s) waiting to happen ! Hence the error for using uninitialized data.

Comment: i will remember this thanks  @engf-010

Comment: Since you are not reading/writing `wstring` values the "normal" way, and more importantly, because you are mixing in binary data, I suggest you switch to `ifstream`/`ofstream` in binary mode. But then you will have to change `wofs.write(date.c_str(), s1);` to `ofs.write((const char*)date.c_str(), s1 * sizeof(wchar_t));` and so on. Also, `wchar_t date[sz];` is not portable code, use `wstring date; date.resize(sz);` instead. Also, `wchar_t` itself is not portable, so consider saving the strings to the file in UTF-8 format instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau still happening the same thing

Comment: what is the problem with wchar_t date[sz];

Comment: sz is variable and array dimension should be compiletime constant values in standard C++ (there are compiler nonstandard extensions that support this).

Comment: oh you are right.. updated the code but the problem remains the same

Comment: `wofs.write((wchar_t*)&s1, sizeof(s1))` writes `sizeof(s1)` characters, not `sizeof(s1)` bytes. As usually `wchar_t` is larger than one byte, you are writing out the binary representation of `s1` plus whatever garbage happens to follow it in memory. Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of a buffer overrun.

Comment: `totalSize` counts the total number of characters in all strings, but doesn't include the bytes taken by the size prefixes. This may or may not matter - you don't show why you are computing `totalSize`, how this value is eventually used.

Comment: `wifs.read((wchar_t*)&sz, sizeof(sz));` exhibits a similar buffer overrun, but this one is worse - you are actually writing garbage all over some random piece of memory, rather than merely accessing it.

Comment: `this->date = date;` is another buffer overrun, as `date` is not NUL-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `std::ofstream` which allows aliasing `(char*)&integer`, you cannot use `std::wofstream` to write binary data by aliasing `(wchar_t*)&integer`. You can reproduce the error by the following wrong code:

```
std::wofstream fout(L"unicode.txt", ios::binary);
int integer = 0x12345678;
fout.write((wchar_t*)&integer, sizeof(integer));
if(!fout.good())
    cout << "problem\n"; //<- write fails, file size should be zero
```

The purpose of `std::wstream` is to convert the bytes in the file in to wide char, which is 2 bytes. If you are handling binary data, you are working with single bytes, so use `std::fstream` instead.

Visual Studio has a special constructor and `open` method for `fstream` which allows using Unicode filenames, this will give the necessary Unicode compatibility to handle files with Unicode names.

```
void Write(ofstream& ofs)
{
    size_t sz = date.size();
    ofs.write((char*)&sz, sizeof(sz)); ofs.write((char*)date.c_str(), sz);

    sz = number.size(); 
    ofs.write((char*)&sz, sizeof(sz)); ofs.write((char*)number.c_str(), sz);

    sz = vender_code.size();
    ofs.write((char*)&sz, sizeof(sz)); ofs.write((char*)vender_code.c_str(), sz);
}

void Read(std::ifstream& ifs)
{
    size_t sz = 0;

    ifs.read((char*)&sz, sizeof(sz)); date.resize(sz + 1, 0);
    ifs.read((char*)&date[0], sz);

    ifs.read((char*)&sz, sizeof(sz)); number.resize(sz + 1, 0);
    ifs.read((char*)&number[0], sz);

    ifs.read((char*)&sz, sizeof(sz)); vender_code.resize(sz + 1, 0);
    ifs.read((char*)&vender_code[0], sz);
}
```

And make sure to open the file in binary mode:

```
purchase_order_details info;
info.date = L"date";
info.number = L"number";
info.vender_code = L"vendor_code";

ofstream fout(L"unicode.txt", std::ios::binary);
info.Write(fout);
fout.close();

ifstream fin(L"unicode.txt", std::ios::binary);
info.Read(fin);
```

Alternatively, convert the Unicode from UTF16 to UTF8, and use Standard Library's input/out `>>`/`<<` operators to write integers in plain text. The output file will be compatible with POSIX also.